# store images in offline storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm creating a speed dial extension for myself (I know there's a lot of speed dial extension, but most of them will display ads, and my antivirus threat them as PuP), I wanted to save website's logo image, let user either place one picture by themselves, or give the url of the picture.

I am stuck with how to save images in chrome's offline storage (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#table), there's no example for saving other file types.

How do I save picture on google chrome's offline storage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Take a look at [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage):

  - 5MB data limit or unlimited if the extension has the `unlimitedStorage` permission
  - content scripts can directly access user data without the need for a background page.
  - It's asynchronous and therefore faster than the blocking and serial localStorage API.
  - User data can be stored as objects (the localStorage API stores data in strings). Only simple JSON-serializable objects are supported, though.
- `localStorage` serializes everything so you'll have to convert the image to a dataurl first:

  ```js
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', favicon_url);
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  xhr.onload = function(r) {
      if (xhr.status != 200) {
          return;
      }
      localStorage.icon = 'data:image/png;base64,' +
          btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(xhr.response)));
  }
  xhr.send();
  ```

  This is a simplified example which assumes `png` image type.
- <s>[chrome.fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) might be a better choice.</s> (not suitable for an extension as it's only for apps)
- [HTML5 FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/): currently could be the best choice but the API is no longer maintained by W3C so it's unclear whether it stays in the future.

Comment: The filesystem API is indeed very good for this.  I still sync with the server because even 'permanent' data does get wiped from the client sooner or later but for short term storage such as making mobile signal coverage maps the file system API is ideal.

Comment: If I use fileSystem API, how do I save picture that user have defined/downloaded?

Comment: The filesystem API works fine in web pages too.  Let me assemble an example for you...

Comment: @Max Murphy, I've linked `chrome.fileSystem`, not HTML5 FileSystem API which I already forgot because it was announced on public-webapps that [...] the API is Chrome-specific and [...] is no longer being standardized with the W3C. ([source](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/))

Comment: Aaaaand you forgot the `chrome.storage` API as the saner alternative to `localStorage`.

Comment: 5 MB limit is flexible (`"unlimitedStorage"` permission)

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the image to a data URL.  At that point it's just a string so it's easy to save.  For examples of data URL images see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples

I usually convert images to data URLs on the command line with `cat whatever.png | base64` but there are a number of websites that will do it for you, if you prefer.

Hope that helps.

To create images yourself (Remember to change the mime type to whatever you need):

`cat /apple/Downloads/80.png | printf "%s%s%s" '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' "$(base64 -w0)" '" alt="Red dot" />'`

Examples of sites that will create data URLs for you:

- http://www.base64-image.de/step-1.php
- http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker

I've made a fiddle to show how to use the file API to get an image as a data URL: https://jsfiddle.net/quvvtkwr/

Comment: the answer would be ok if you covered how to convert programatically the image to a data url. its easy using canvas. note he wants the user to pick an image so your commandline method  isnt good.